# Issue with Full Screen in Zoom Call

Tags: display, applications

I am not sure if this happens with other applications, but I have seen it happen in Zoom. Whenever I am in a call and go into a full screen view, the application goes into full screen mode, but only takes up like 1/4 of the top left of the screen and becomes unresponsive until I move it to a different workspace, where it is no longer in full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a zoom bug not elementary issue, it happens to all my devices using linux in general and teams or skype does not make the same issue, just enter full screen from elementary itself not from zoom (search shortcuts for full screen).